# Enterprise Library 5.0 configuration in VS2010 (Web) Express

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

Is it possible to use Enterprise Library Configuration Tool in VS 2010 Express?

I'm trying to configure TransientFaultHandling block for azure and can't download the Tool into VS nor find TransientFaultHandling Block in the EntLib Config that comes with EntLib 5.0 installation...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use config directly from visual studio express. But separate config tool (installed with Entlib) should work without problem. If you can't find some type copy all dlls and exes of your project to the entlib bin folder (same where config exe is). Then your types should be visible. This solution always worked for me.